# Retrieving an enum using 'valueOf' throws RuntimeException - What to use instead?

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enum

```
enum Animal implements Mammal {
   CAT, DOG;

   public static Mammal findMammal(final String type) {
      for (Animal a : Animal.values()) {
         if (a.name().equals(type)) {
            return a;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I had originally used the `Enum.valueOf(Animal.class, "DOG");` to find a particular Animal. However, I was unaware that if a match is not found, an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown. I thought that maybe a null was returned. So this gives me a problem. I don't want to catch this `IllegalArgumentException` if a match is not found. I want to be able to search all enums of type `Mammal` and I don't want to have to implement this static '`findMammal`' for each enum of type `Mammal`. So my question is, what would be the most auspicious design decision to implement this behaviour? I will have calling code like this:

```
public class Foo {
   public Mammal bar(final String arg) {
      Mammal m = null;
      if (arg.equals("SomeValue")) {
         m = Animal.findMammal("CAT");
      } else if (arg.equals("AnotherValue") {
         m = Human.findMammal("BILL");
      }
      // ... etc
   }
}
```

As you can see, I have different types of Mammal - 'Animal', 'Human', which are enums. I don't want to have to implement 'findMammal' for each Mammal enum. I suppose the best bet is just create a utility class which takes a Mammal argument and searches that? Maybe there's a neater solution.

Comment: You say that you don't want to catch the exception, why? How are you going to handle the case when the type doesn't exits?

Comment: Because it's a runtime exception and catching runtime exceptions is a major no-no. This is my predicament

Comment: `Animal implements Mammal`? Shouldn't this be the other way around? Mammals are a subclass of Animals...

Comment: Animals, humans, etc.. are all Mammals. Notwithstanding, it was just a cursory example

Comment: @joeblackdev If I understood correctly, You cant take Mammal as an argument to search, because its not an enum its just an interface there wont be values() method in it.

Comment: No, they aren't. Crocodiles are animals, but not mammals.

Comment: @SajanChandran I don't follow you. I take a string argument. Where does it mention that a Mammal argument is passed to the 'findMammal' method?

Comment: @Joeblackdev: That kind of generalized rule is causing you unneeded frustration. `parseInt()` throws a runtime exception, but that doesn't mean I shouldn't catch it when validating user input. This is why I asked about how you were planning on using it. If you have a situation where you will regularly not find a result, an exception being thrown is no different than returning null. It is just an indication that no match was found and you need to properly handle that situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about creating a `HashMap<String, Mammal>`? You only need to do it once...

```
public class Foo {

  private static final Map<String, Mammal> NAME_TO_MAMMAL_MAP;

  static {
    NAME_TO_MAMMAL_MAP = new HashMap<String, Mammal>();
    for (Human human : EnumSet.allOf(Human.class)) {
      NAME_TO_MAMMAL_MAP.put(human.name(), human);
    }
    for (Animal animal : EnumSet.allOf(Animal.class)) {
      NAME_TO_MAMMAL_MAP.put(animal.name(), animal);
    }
  }

  public static Mammal bar(final String arg) {
    return NAME_TO_MAMMAL_MAP.get(arg);
  }
}
```

Notes:

- This will return `null` if the name doesn't exist
- This won't detect a name collision
- You may want to use an immutable map of some description (e.g. via [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com))
- You may wish to write a utility method to create an immutable name-to-value map for a general enum, then just merge the maps :)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on the hashmap approach? Thanks

Comment: Human.values() is almost equal to EnumSet.allOf(Human.class) and could be used in foreach loop.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [getEnum](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html#getEnum(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) Method vom the apache [EnumUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html) library. It returns the enum or `null` if not found.

```
EnumUtils.getEnum(Animal.class, "CAT");
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to touch every Enum (understandable), a utility method is the way to go. I understand not wanting to catch the exception in your code, catching it in the method should be fine, though:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T findEnumValue(Class<T> type, String name) {
    if (name == null)
        return null;
    try {
        return Enum.valueOf(type, name.toUpperCase());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hhmm, I'm not happy about that though. I want to avoid catching the runtime exception. I just don't like doing that.

Comment: If you really don't want to catch runtime exceptions (seems pretty arbitrary, to be honest), you can always search the values, or use a backing map - similar to Jon's answer, but populated automatically and not limited to Animal enums.

Answer (score 8):

You can use guava library. [Enums](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Enums.html#valueOfFunction%28java.lang.Class%29) class allows this:

```
Enums.valueOfFunction(MyEnum.class).apply(id);
```

Comment: Seems removed, probably in favor of `Enums.getIfPresent(Country.class, countryInput).or(Country.DEFAULT);`, which is nice. Link is still OK.

Comment: Since `Enum` variable can be `null` in Java, `Enums.getIfPresent(Country.class, countryInput).orNull();` can also be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I don't get the question but I also needed a `valueOf` that returns `null` instead of throwing an exception, so I created this utility method:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(T[] values, String name)
{
    for (T value : values) {
        if (value.name().equals(name)) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
Animal a = valueOf(Animal.values(), "CAT");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your code. If you need your function to return null when it doesn't find something, simply return it:

```
enum Animal implements Mammal {
   CAT, DOG;

   public static Mammal findMammal(final String type) {
      for (Animal a : Animal.values()) {
         if (a.name().equals(type)) {
            return a;
         }
      }
      return null; // this line works if nothing is found.
   }
}
```

No technology will help if you would do the same error and forget to create some return value for every possible case.

Your choose : Enum - EnumMaps - HashMap depends on the dynamics of your data. Enums constants can't be created in runtime. On the other hand, you don't need to check many things in runtime - compiler will do it. And you very probably will forget to check something. What Jon Skeet manages easily could give you a headache.

Answer (score 0):

If you can say

```
m = Animal.findMammal("CAT");
```

Why can't you say

```
m = Animal.CAT;
```

The "CAT" will have to match the enums name anyway and in your Example, "CAT" is not derived from a parameter but is hardcoded.

**UPDATE**
(perhaps more to the point of the question)

It is a bit elaborate, but...

```
public interface Mammal{

    public void doMammalStuff();

    public static interface Finder{
        public Mammal find(String name, Class<Enum<?>> enumType);
    }

    public static Finder FINDER = new Finder(){
        public Mammal find(String name, Class<Enum<?>> enumType) {
            return enumType.forName( name );
    };
    };
}
```

Then you could call

```
Mammal m = Mammal.FINDER.find( "CAT", Animal.class );
```

Your implementation of find() may look different (i.e. not throwing an exception).

Comment: I should have elaborated. My apologies. The argument supplied to Animal.findMammal is dynamic. I hardcoded it for brevity

Comment: almost thought so. My Edit shows a version that binds the find-implementation to the interface (without a need to know the enum type that implements it).

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.common.base.Enums;

return Enums.getIfPresent(Animal.class, value).or("default_animal"));
```

OR

```
return Enums.getIfPresent(Animal.class, value).orNull());
```

OR

```
if (Enums.getIfPresent(Animal.class, value).isPresent()) {
    // take action
}
```